# Can "long long [(,)]" declaration somehow work in C?

Tags: c, declaration

I am preparing for our programming test and I read this `long long A[(10,10)]` declaration (it was in some previous test in our course), which I have no more information about. Only other thing I know about it, is that it is **not possible** to initialize variable declared this way by calling `A[5][1]=something`. Otherwise, I would assume it is some kind of 2D array.
It also could be [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) but the gcc compiler actually doesn't recognise it.

> abc.c:3:16: error: expected ']'
>           long long A[10,10];
>                        ^ abc.c:3:13: note: to match this '['
>           long long A[10,10];

Do you have any clue if it is a thing, or just some nonsense? (I was trying to Google it, but these things aren't that easy to find...)
Thank you.

Comment: Please cite your source.

Comment: Where did you get this declaration from?

Comment: @ForceBru It was in some previous test for our course.

Comment: @TGar, perhaps it was the wrong answer for a multiple choice question? Even putting parentheses around the size of the array like this: `int test[(10)];` is invalid.

Comment: @ForceBru It actually was in question among other declarations and we should choose which l-value initialization can be used if we have this declarations.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Heh, gcc -version is showing: Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So you're saying it should be the same as long long A[10]? (e.g. for long long A[10,7]; it is the same as long long A[7] ) And is there some reason for the () parentheses?

Comment: I was wrong. According to [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) it can be any expression *except* the comma operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question "Do you have any clue if it is a thing, or just some nonsense?": Any declaration which is that non-intuitive that experienced programmers have to consult cpp reference is IMHO clearly nonsense.

I tested expression `long long A[(10,10)]` with Apple LLVM 8.0 compiler and C99 language dialect, and it worked. When consulting the  [cpp reference concerning comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator), one can find the following:

> **Top-level** comma operator is also disallowed in array bounds
>
> // int a[2,3]; // error
>
> int a[(2,3)]; // OK, VLA array of size 3 (VLA because (2,3) is not a constant expression)

So `long long A[(10,10)]` seams to be equivalent to `long long A[10]`, where the `10` is the second part of non top-level comma expression `(10,10)`. Interesting thing may be that an array declared this way is treated as VLA (variable length array, which's size is determined at runtime).

Answer (score 4):

In array declarations, a `constant-expression` is expected, which is a subset of `expression`. Specifically, the comma operator and assignment expressions are not part of the set.

Array declarators are a kind of `direct-declarator`:

```
direct-declarator: ... |
    direct-declarator "[" constant-expression? "]";

constant-expression: conditional-expression;

expression: assignment-expression | expression "," assignment-expression;

assignment-expression: conditional-expression |
    unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression;
```

So the grammar doesn't allow for a comma here.

Comment: @SimonRichter It can be a variable length array in C99 or later, in which the expression (10,10) is just the normal comma operator grouped with parenthesis

Comment: Yes, at least according to the grammar in the C language specification. Note that `A[(10,10)]` or `A[(j = 5)]` are allowed in the grammar, but would fail semantic evaluation in a later step in pre-C99 mode.